# Gerenciamento de ligações telefônicas no Android

Tags: android

Minha aplicação precisa saber de duas informações (as que eu não encontrei no **Android** developers): quando uma ligação termina e se esta gastou algum saldo do celular.

Já encontrei os estados **IDLE**, **OFFHOOK** e **RINGING**, mas, não o de **ligação finalizada**....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ligação finalizada" não é um estado. É uma transição de um estado para outro.

O IDLE é o que procura. Se um IDLE acontece após um OFFHOOK é porque houve uma chamada finalizada.